# CUDA thrust library and cudaDeviceReset()

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

When you call cudaDeviceReset() does that make any thrust::device_vectors in scope unusable?

```html
thrust::host_vector<int> h_intVec;
thrust::device_vector<int> d_intVec;

... set the host vector to something...

d_intVec = h_intVec;

... do some GPU stuff ...

h_intVec = d_intVec;

cudaDeviceReset();

d_intVec = h_intVec;
```

I seem to get some back end error when I try to refill the device_vector is their something I don't know about going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they are unusable.

Under the hood, a thrust::device_vector definition creates an allocation on the device.  `cudaDeviceReset` voids all allocations on the device, so the original device_vector is no longer usable.

Comment: is there a way to rebuild or should I use a pointer to a device_vector instead?

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to get rid of the `cudaDeviceReset()` ?  Why are you doing that right in the middle of your code?

Comment: Mostly for lazy reasons to be honest I'm moving a lot of data in multiple vectors host to device and back. I figured between functions it be better to just reset than keep track of what needs to be maintained and just copy back when nessisary.

Comment: I should probably mention I'm working with 2 GPUs one on display the other for purely running CUDA

Comment: That strategy/use of `cudaDeviceReset()` seems like something you would want to change in my opinion.  Anyway I don't know of a way to safely rebuild it.  As a simple test, I was able to work around it via pointers but it seems pretty contorted to me.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it; its something that's bound to change when I re-factor for optimization to reduce copying.

Comment: @AidanPossemiers: Any thrust object is automagically deallocated and cleaned up when it falls out of scope. If you manage varaible scope correctly, you probably should *never* need to programmatically deallocate a thrust device vector.